# Office Excel JS - Find and replace

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I just wonder whether we can find and replace using Office Excel JS? I have read through their [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/) but it does not mention about this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `Range` object has a `find` method to search for a specified string within the range. It returns the range of the first cell with matching text.

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    let table = sheet.tables.getItem("ExpensesTable");
    let searchRange = table.getRange();
    let foundRange = searchRange.find("Food", {
        completeMatch: true, // Match the whole cell value.
        matchCase: false, // Don't match case.
        searchDirection: Excel.SearchDirection.forward // Start search at the beginning of the range.
    });

    foundRange.load("address");
    await context.sync();

    console.log(foundRange.address);
});
```

See [Find a string within a range using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-string-match) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-worksheet-replaceall-member(1)) function replaceAll would do it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).